# Setting the directionality of \tdplotdrawarc in cartesian coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I have an issue with regards to `\tdplotdrawarc` in `TikZ`. Consider the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing} %  interesection is not needed
%\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\pgfmathsetmacro{\ax}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ay}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\az}{1}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\axx}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ayy}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\azz}{1}


\draw[->,red, thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,1,1) node[anchor=west]{$\vec{n}$};
\draw[dashed,red] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,1);
\draw[dashed,red] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (0,0,0);
\draw[dashed, black] (0,0,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (1,1,1);
\draw[dashed, black] (1,1,0) -- (1,0,0);
\draw[fill=red,opacity=0.1] (-3,-3,0) -- (-3,3,0) -- (3,3,0) -- (3,-3,0) -- cycle;

\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_main_coords,->]{(0,0,0)}{1}{0}
        {45}{anchor=east}{$\alpha$}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image]

What I would like to do is something like:

[image]

but I do not want to use:

```
\tdplotgetpolarcoords{\ax}{\ay}{\az}
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\tdplotresphi}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{1}{0}
{\tdplotrestheta}{anchor=east}{$\alpha$}
```

to draw the arc, but stick to cartesian coordinates. Is this possible? And If so, how?